# Why php function doesn't update array values

Tags: php, arrays, function

I'm new at php/programming and would like to know why this doesn't work the way I think It should.

I have an array and I'd like to modify one of its values with a function.

I've been reading and following some tutorials and think it has to do with the variable scope? Or maybe this is just not the way to approach something like this and should use other methods?

```
<?php
$someArray = array("value1"=> 0, "value2" => 0);
function test ($a) {
    if ( 5 > 4 ) {
        $a["value1"] += 1;
        echo $a["value1"] . "<br/>";            
    }
}
test($someArray);
echo $someArray["value1"];
?>
```

What I don't get is why it works when I echo inside the function to get the new value of "value1", but outside it doesn't work. I'd really appreciate any help/guidance and sorry if this is just too dumb or wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are passing as a copy of the array. You should pass the array using the address to reflect the changes done inside the array. Use `&` (passing as reference):

```
$someArray = array("value1"=> 0, "value2" => 0);
function test (&$a) {   //Use & here
               ^
    if ( 5 > 4 ) {
        $a["value1"] += 1;
        echo $a["value1"] . "<br/>";            
    }
}
test($someArray);
echo $someArray["value1"];
```

**Here is the Explanation:** (fetched from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37561463/5447994))

[image: explanation]

Read this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/373419/5447994) too.

---

Other way is to return the value from function. Inside the function, use return and capture it outside:

```
$someArray = array("value1"=> 0, "value2" => 0);
function test ($a) {
    if ( 5 > 4 ) {
        $a["value1"] += 1;
        echo $a["value1"] . "<br/>";            
    }
    return $a; //Return here
}
$someArray = test($someArray);  //Capture here
echo $someArray["value1"];
```

Comment: What a great illustration 

Comment: So many years of PHP coding (for WordPress). Never ever wrote any `&$arg` pass by reference code. I always thought of it as some optional thing, never ever had any issues, I just do not write code like that. I think it's more an issue for people coming from other programming languages with pointers and shit. I just always return things and work with that. I do not like this passing by reference at all, it just makes code harder to understand.

So my guess is, passing by reference is more memory efficient, no copy into new var, but you should never think like that.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

1) return updated array `$a` from function

2) receive that array in `$someArray` again

```
$someArray = array("value1"=> 0, "value2" => 0);
function test ($a) {
    if ( 5 > 4 ) {
        $a["value1"] += 1;
    }
    return $a;
}
$someArray = test($someArray);
echo "Updated ".$someArray["value1"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function echoes stuff but does not alter or return value. What you want to achieve is to change/alter the value, so you can return this value instead of echo in your function and set a variable for that value to echo out. Below, you can find how you should do;

```
<?php
$someArray = array("value1"=> 0, "value2" => 0);
function test ($a) {
    if ( 5 > 4 ) {
        $a["value1"] += 1;
        return $a["value1"] . "<br/> YEY we did it";            
    }
}
echo test($someArray);
?>
```

And check it here in [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/65bbde6be6f08ea16123951788d383f19cf0e78d)

Answer (score 0):

Use pass by reference

```
test(&$someArray);
```